# Filter multiple rows of a dataframe based on values of multiple rows in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

genes

| chr | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1 | 5 |
| C2 | 7 | 15 |
| C3 | 20 | 30 |

positions

| chr | pos |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 3 |
| C2 | 6 |
| C3 | 20 |
| C4 | 25 |

I want to filter the values of each row in the second dataframe (positions) based on the values of a row in the first dataframe(genes). The filtering criteria are that the value of the column chr should be the same between both dataframes **and** the value pos should be larger or equal compared to the value start **and** smaller or equal to the value end.

The filtered dataframe would be the following:

| chr | pos |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 3 |
| C3 | 20 |

I wanna do it with dplyr preferably!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: With `dplyr` you can join and then filter, or you can use the `fuzzyjoin` package to do a non-equi join, or you can use `data.table` which does non-equi joins natively.